# I'm learning C++ lambda function. Why does it have this output?

Tags: c++, lambda

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
int* p = nullptr;
auto fun()
{
    int a = 1;
    p = &a;
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    auto z = [&a]() {std::cout << &a << "   "; a++; std::cout << "lambda call " << a << std::endl; };
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    auto z = fun();
    std::cout << *p << "\n";
    z();
    z();
    
    fun()();
}
```

and the output is

```
0x7fffd10af15c
1
0x7fffd10af15c   lambda call 21880
0x7fffd10af15c   lambda call 21880
0x7fffd10af15c
0x7fffd10af15c   lambda call 21880
```

The version of my compiler is gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
Why do i have this output? Is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: *"Why do i have this output?"* -- because that is the output produced by that code. Were you expecting something different? Without an explanation of your intent, I'll have to rely on your code to tell me what it is supposed to do, and according to the code, your output is as expected. *Also, without an explanation, this question has little to no hope of helping someone else in the future, because no reasonable search would find it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that `a` is a local variable in the `fun` function and gets destroyed by the time `fun` finishes. That means, the returned lambda `z` is referencing an area on the stack where `a` used to be, but now when `z` is called this area is used for something else (this is why you see 21880).

In order to avoid this problem you need to prevent `a` being destroyed when leaving `fun`'s scope. One way is to declare `a` as a global variable, just like `p`. The other one is to make it a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do i have this output?

The given program has **undefined behavior** since `a` is a local variable and will be destroyed once the function returns and so it(`a`) should not be referenced again.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

To solve this make sure that you don't reference the local variables out of their scope either by making them(`a`) a `static` or `global`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>